# How to fix "dictionary update sequence element # 0 has length 104; 2 is required" error

Tags: python, django

I want to create a login page, when the username and password are incorrect there is this error "dictionary update sequence element # 0 has length ... is required". How to correct this error?

```
forms.py
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required=False)

views.py
class LoginView(View):
    template_name = 'login/index.html'
    form_class = LoginForm

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                next_var = request.GET.get('next')
                # redirect to url in next var else return to login home page
                return redirect('%s' % next_var) if next_var else redirect('%s' % settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

```
When the fields are not filled there is this error "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 104; 2 is required" that appears. but when I log in and I go back to the login page to log in without anything filled in I'm reported that the fields are not filled
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import login, signup, logout, settings, profile

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signup.SignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('signin/', login.LoginView.as_view(), name='signin'),
    path('logout/', logout.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('account/', settings.SettingView.as_view(), name='account'),
    path('account/avatar/', settings.SetAvatarView.as_view(), name='set-avatar'),
    path('account/name/', settings.SetNameView.as_view(), name='set-name'),
    path('account/biography/', settings.SetBiographyView.as_view(), name='set-biography'),
    path('account/birthday', settings.SetBirthdayView.as_view(), name='set-birthday'),
    path('account/gender/', settings.SetGenderView.as_view(), name='set-gender'),
    path('account/password/', settings.SetPasswordView.as_view(), name='set-password'),
    path('account/dark-theme/', settings.SetDarkView.as_view(), name='set-dark-mode'),
    path('account/color/', settings.SetColorView.as_view(), name='set-color'),

    path('u/<int:id>/', profile.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py` and the full backtrace please?

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks i have solved the problem by putting the code of context in comment.

from . models import AccountModel

def accounts(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        account = AccountModel.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
        return {'account': account}
    else:
        return request
```